# Facebook SDK (Android): events can be seen in 'test events' debug view but are not reported in campaign manager

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

When I test my app (either by launching it from Android Studio or the app in production on Google Play), I see the events in in 'test events' debug of the Facebook console, as can be seen here:

[image]

Nevertheless, no installs are reported in the AdsManager (but I know that I have installs from my Facebook campaigns even if the CPI increased dramatically).

This problem appeared after upgrading the Facebook SDK from 7.1.0 to 13.1.0 (I changed nothing to else in the code of my app except the version of the Facebook SDK). I rolled back to 7.1.0 and worked again. I don't understand what is the problem with 13.1.0.

Any idea ? Thanks.